# How to nicely include a private NPM dependency in a lerna workspace project?

Tags: npm, devops, yarnpkg, lerna, monorepo

To preface, the project is using lerna with yarn workspaces and we are pulling in an internal NPM package from our private npm registry (not hosted with npm).

I currently understand how .yarnrc and .npmrc files can authenticate to private registries but our current project has settings already changed in these files. A developer could add credentials in these files but then they cannot commit the file to github.

I was hoping to find a solution where a developer on the project can add the private registry credentials in a .env file and then auth with said credentials somehow in a hook before lerna runs "install"

My main goal was to make it easy to work with the project and not rely on having each developer run 'npm login' or some other commands besides just including the correct credentials in their .env file. This also makes it easy for CI/deployment pipelines.

Are there any specific lifecycle hooks that can run before install in a lerna package?